# Normalizing a relation schema with 'abstract' attribute names

Tags: database-design, normalization, relations

I'm a student currently attending a database design course and I'm having some issues normalizing 'abstract' attribute relation schemas from 1NF all the way to 3NF.

When we used examples with 'explicit' values in the lecture I didn't have issues normalizing those relation schemas, but as soon as it gets 'abstract' I just can't do it.

Given the following relation schema `(R, a)` with `a = {A, B, C, D, E, G, H, I}` and functional dependencies `FDs = {GH → A, AH → BC, CHI → B, B → C, A → B, CE → D, BC → H, D → A, AG → B, H → I}`. I first reduced the left and right sides of the functional dependencies to find the minimal cover `M = {GH → A, CH → B, B → C, A → B, CE → D, B → H, D → A, AG → B, H → I}`.

In the lecture we agreed that this sort of 'abstract' relation schema would already be in 1NF.

I chose `G, E` and `D` as my key as `G` and `E` can't be determined by any other attribute and `D` seemed good as it determines `A` which then determines all other attributes.

I came to the following solution for the normalization to 2NF.

Solution

- `{D, A, B, C, H, I}`
- `{G, H, A}`
- `{E, C, D}`

I'm pretty sure my solution is incorrect. I'm not even really sure where to start and I haven't started normalizing to 3NF as I think it would be good to at least have a correct 2NF to start from. Any help is much appreciated.

**Where do I start to normalize the given relation schema to 2NF and 3NF?**

Comment: I think you should start by finding **all candidate keys**, don't just choose one.

Comment: Isn't `G, E` and `D` already a candidate key as I can't remove one of the three without loosing the ability to determine all other attributes?

Comment: Yes, `GED` is a candidate key. But isn't `GEA` as well? And `GEH` too? (and possibly others)?

Comment: Yes they are but I don't see the benefit of searching for others when I already found one. Can you explain?

Comment: The definition of 2NF requires you know which attribute are prime and which not and what are all the candidate keys: "a relation is in 2NF if it is in 1NF and no **non-prime attribute** is dependent on any proper subset of **any candidate key** of the relation."

Comment: I echo the comment from @ypercube.  2NF and 3NF are defined in terms of candidate keys, not just the primary key.  In fact, the choice  of which candidate key will become the primary key is a judgement call on the part of the designer.  That call doesn't change how normalized the scema is.